# Do file attributes in CDs and DVDs change if you access them?

Tags: filesystems, dvd, compact-disc, file-attributes, optical-media

I have snooped over my boyfriend's old CDs and DVDs. I opened and copied (with copy paste) some of the files (jpeg and videos). Does this action change the file attributes (date accessed, etc.) of the files I messed around? What if it was a multisession CD or DVD? Does it work like a USB stick exactly or do I have to burn something in it in order to change the attributes?

Comment: Yes if you open them it will be accessed by you. But it will not change the originals as long as you did not mess with them. Is this your question or are you trying to access them and cant?

Comment: I am afraid of the case he checks the files and the file attributes are more recent than the originals,and so he will understand i searched them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.I just copied some files to my pc and opened to see some photos and videos.What do you mean if i messed around with them?Sorry but i am so afraid

Comment: CD/DVD are generally read only. So reading them and copying the data won't change the original.

Comment: Thank you very much!What about if the cd or dvd was burned and left open to let files to be added later(i think this is called miltisession)?Does this change the attributes,like when accesing a file in a usb stick?

Comment: I don't think any file manager or so on any OS will start a new session/track for what you've mentioned. Not sure about those +/-RW discs formatted to UDF or DVD-RAM (which can be formatted to FAT32 or so, apparently: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-RAM#Compatibility)